# How to centre the background image of an iOS application window

Tags: ios, background, uiimage, window

I have been looking at how it is possible to centre a background image for an app.  This is primarily to allow me to use a square image to cut down on the amount of resources to be stored (and update when changes are made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I used to achieve the results

```
//  Create the window covering the bounds of the entire screen
self.window = [ [ [ UIWindow alloc ] initWithFrame:[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ] ] autorelease ];

//  Set the background for the game.  This will show on the flip transition.
UIImageView  *bg = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage: [ UIImage imageNamed: @"Background.png" ] ];
bg.frame = self.window.bounds;
bg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

[ self.window addSubview: bg ];
[ self.window sendSubviewToBack: bg ];
[ bg release ];
```